# insert into dataset

Tags: c#, dataset

what is the command to insert data into dataset?
what is wrong with the following code:

```
DataSetReasons.Data_Tracker_RcodeDataTable GRX = 
    new DataSetReasons.Data_Tracker_RcodeDataTable();

DataSetReasons.Data_Tracker_RcodeRow rowx = 
    DataSetReasons.Data_Tracker_RcodeRow();

rowx.dtrc_id = 5;
rowx.eval_id = 28;
rowx.dtcr_StaffNum = "505651";
rowx.dtrc_RC1 = "C";
rowx.dtrc_RC2 = "A";
rowx.dtrc_RM1 = 2;
rowx.dtrc_RM2 = 4;

GRX.Rows.Add(rowx);
```

Comment: Is there a `GRX.Commit` or `GTX.SubmitChanges` (or similarly named) method that you need to call to actually save the changes?

Comment: i am missing new keyword when creating a new row. anything else looks good to me. what error do you get? what exactly is your problem?

Comment: the error in "Data_Tracker_RcodeRow()" but when I add "new" to the code, then the whole line after the word new gets underlined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, thanks to everyone... here is the code:

```
DataSetReasons.Data_Tracker_RcodeDataTable GRX =
new DataSetReasons.Data_Tracker_RcodeDataTable();

GRX.Rows.Add(13, 28, "C", 5, "A", 2, TextBox2.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

you must add your datatable GRX  to your dataset DataSetReasons.

```
   DataSetReasons.Data_Tracker_RcodeDataTable GRX = 
    new DataSetReasons.Data_Tracker_RcodeDataTable();

DataSetReasons.Data_Tracker_RcodeRow rowx = 
    DataSetReasons.Data_Tracker_RcodeRow();

rowx.dtrc_id = 5;
rowx.eval_id = 28;
rowx.dtcr_StaffNum = "505651";
rowx.dtrc_RC1 = "C";
rowx.dtrc_RC2 = "A";
rowx.dtrc_RM1 = 2;
rowx.dtrc_RM2 = 4;

GRX.Rows.Add(rowx);

    DataSetReasons.Tables.Add(GRX);//<--
```

Comment: where exactly? and do I have to change anything in the above code? sorry but I'm a noob.

Comment: in the end of treatment user1503894

Comment: got this error:  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'GAPP.DataSetReasons.Tables.get'

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with the below line:

DataSetReasons.Data_Tracker_RcodeRow rowx =  GRX.NewRow();

Regarding adding the datatable to a dataset, you have to create a dataset object and add the datatable to the dataset.

Comment: got error with "GRX.NewRow()" : Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataRow' to 'GAPP.DataSetReasons.Data_Tracker_RcodeRow'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)